# How to group some values rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using rails 4. And i'm trying to output menu navigation. I got tble PlaceType with category and title columns. There are 6 categories and i want to output Category only 1 time and then output all titles, that brlong to this ategory. How can i achieve that?

```
<% @types = PlaceType.all %>
  <% @types.each do |type| %>
    <ul><%= type.category %>
    <li><%= type.title %></li>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
```

That's my way of sloving this problem:

```
<% @types = PlaceType.all %>
  <% @types.group_by(&:category).each do |category, type| %>
    <ul><%= category %>
  <% type.each do |t|%>
    <li><%= t.title %></li>
  <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `group_by` method available in Array.

`@types.group_by {|type| type.category}`

Will give you a hash that looks something like this:

```
{
  "Category A" => ["Title 1", "Title 2"],
  "Category B" => ["Title 3"],
  "Category C" => ["Title 4", "Title 5"]
}
```

Now you can loop through the resulting hash instead, to display titles under each category.

Comment: i managed to output like this: `@types.group_by(&:category).each do |category, type|` only one problem now. i don't know how to render title normally, not like active record